# Pyomegle: ImportError: cannot import name 'OmegleClient' from partially initialized module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to code a pyomegle bot and I keep getting this error every time I try and run it. I have tried running it with the **interpreter** and in the **terminal**, all to no evail. I am using Python version `2.7.17 32-bit` and already tried version `3.8.1 32-bit`, and using **vscode** as a text editor.

`pip --version` produces:

```
pip 20.0.2 from c:\users\MYNAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

`pip freeze` produces:

```
aiohttp==3.6.2
astroid==2.3.3
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.5
beautifulsoup4==4.8.2
certifi==2019.11.28
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.3
colored==1.4.2
discord.py==1.3.2
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
mccabe==0.6.1
mechanize==0.4.5
multidict==4.7.5
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.19
pygame==1.9.6
pylint==2.4.4
PyNaCl==1.3.0
pyomegle==1.5
requests==2.23.0
six==1.13.0
soupsieve==2.0
toml==0.10.0
urllib3==1.25.8
webencodings==0.5.1
websockets==8.1
wrapt==1.11.2
yarl==1.4.2
youtube-dl==2020.2.16
youtube-search==0.1.3
```

I have already used the command below to install pyomegle:

`pip install pyomegle`

This is the error that I recive every time I try and run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\pyomegle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyomegle import OmegleClient, OmegleHandler
  File "c:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\pyomegle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyomegle import OmegleClient, OmegleHandler
ImportError: cannot import name 'OmegleClient' from partially initialized module 'pyomegle' (most likely due to a circular import) (c:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\pyomegle.py)
```

This is my code, there are no other files associated with it:

```
from pyomegle import OmegleClient, OmegleHandler

"""
    Omegle inteface for python

    /next
        starts a new conversation
    /exit
        exits chat session
"""

h = OmegleHandler(loop=True)            # session loop
c = OmegleClient(h, wpm=47, lang='en')  # 47 words per minute
c.start()

while 1:
    input_str = raw_input('')           # string input

    if input_str.strip() == '/next':
        c.next()                        # new conversation
    elif input_str.strip() == '/exit':
        c.disconnect()                  # disconnect chat session
        break
    else:
        c.send(input_str)               # send string
```

I mainly copied the pyomegle example from the readme in their official GitHub repository located here: `https://github.com/elias94/pyomegle`

Comment: When you run `pip freeze` what's the output ? Also, what's the output of `python --version`

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using Python 2?

Comment: updated original post

Comment: did you find out where the problem is?

Comment: You have named your own script `pyomegle.py`.  *That's* what's being imported, not the actual module you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue using atom as an editor, I fixed it by using IDLE instead.

Edit: After reinstalling python for a different reason this no longer works.

Comment: What does IDLE refer to? Please provide a little description and a link to more information.

Comment: IDLE is python's default IDE, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE) so it comes with python when you install it. When I used this instead of any other editor (atom in my case) to run my python code the issue did not  occur. But now this fix doesn't work anymore.